# Download .xls file using Spring boot y Apache POI does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to implement a method that downloads an .xls file with the records of a table from a database. I am working without any template to focus on the backend, the problem is that when I run the application and the corresponding method, the download does not start and the records "appears" on the screen

[image]

ClienteService:

```
@Override
    public ByteArrayInputStream exportData() throws Exception {
        String[] columnas = {"Número Cliente", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Dirección", "Activo"};

        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Clientes");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

        for(int i=0; i<columnas.length; i++){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(columnas[i]);
        }

        List<E01_cliente> clientes = (List<E01_cliente>) clienteRepository.findAll();
        int initRow = 1;
        for(E01_cliente c : clientes){
            row = sheet.createRow(initRow);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(c.getNro_cliente());
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(c.getNombre());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(c.getApellido());
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(c.getDireccion());
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(c.isActivo());
            initRow++;
        }

        workbook.write(stream);
        workbook.close();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
    }
```

Method of Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/descargar")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> exportData() throws Exception {
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = clienteService.exportData();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Dispotion", "attachment; filename=clientes.xls");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(new InputStreamResource(stream));
}
```

Entity Cliente:

```
@Entity
public class E01_cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int nro_cliente;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String direccion;
    private boolean activo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<E01_factura> facturas;
    //Getters and Setters ignored
```

Comment: You do not set the content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Content-Disposition` instead of `Content-Dispotion` as Header

```
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=clientes.xls");
```